# Solving initial value problem using Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

Use Laplace transform to solve the following initial–value problems.

a). $y'' + y = e^{−t}\cos 2t,   \\ y(0) = 2, y′(0) = 1$

After using the concept of partial fraction and using Elementary Laplace Transforms I get:

$$\frac{S}{10(S^2+1)} + \frac{1}{5(s^2 + 1)} - \frac{S}{10((S + 1)^2)+4}$$

For the first and second fraction by inverse Laplace transform I get:

$$\frac{1}{10}\;\cos(t) +\frac{1}{5}\; \sin(t)\:$$ The third one is confusing me. I was trying $e^{at} \cos bt$. But there is a plus sign and no value for "a". Any ideas or suggestions to help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have got the fractions correctly, the third fraction could be done as follows:
$$\frac{s}{(s+1)^2+4}=\frac{s\color{red}{+1}\color{blue}{-1}}{(s+1)^2+4}=\frac{s\color{red}{+1}}{(s+1)^2+4}+\frac{\color{blue}{-1}}{(s+1)^2+4}\\=\frac{S}{S^2+4}|_{S\to s\color{red}{+1}}\color{blue}{-}\frac{1}2\frac{2}{S^2+4}|_{S\to s+1}$$
$$=e^{-t}\cos 2t\color{blue}{-}\frac{1}2e^{-t}\sin 2t$$

Note that: $$\mathcal{L}(e^{at}f(t))=F(s)|_{s\to s-1}$$

Comment: Amazing.Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @Avinesh: Welcome! $(-:$

Comment: How did you get -1/2 in front of $e^{-t}$

Comment: Got it. To balance out 2 in the numerator.

Comment: I wish to post my final solution (Scanned image) for verification. Am I welcome to do so.

Comment: @Avinesh: My int line gets troubled so sorry for the delay in response, but Yes. Plz do. (-: